# Geometry problem: Find the ratio of side of parallelogram to produced side.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I found this geometry question in IMO-2015 (conducted by the Science Olympiad Foundation, India) paper. It goes like this:

ABCD is a parallelogram and L is a point on DB. The produced line AL meets BC at M. Given that **DL = 3LB**, find $\frac{AB}{CN}$ or **AB:CN**.

[image]

The options are: 
[A] 1:2 
[B] 4:5 
[C] 1:4 
[D] 3:2

I tried this: 
Join the diagonal AC.
Let DL = 3x, so LB = x 
Let AC intersect BD at E. 
ABDC is parallelogram 
$\therefore$ DE = EB. 
$\therefore$ DE = 2x, EL = LB = x

I have done till this and I have not idea what to do next. Can anyone give a hint or solution for this problem?

Comment: Now it’s fine. Earlier it was misleading wrt the source of the problem. I have removed my downvote.

Comment: Hint: just compare $\triangle ALB \,$ to $\, \triangle NLD$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triangles LAB and DLN are similar.
Therefore, DN/AB = DL/LB
But DN = DC+CN
So, 1 + CN/AB =3
AB/CN = 1/2
**Option A** is correct

Answer (score 2):

No need to introduce new points. Since $AB,CD$ are parallel, $\triangle ABL$ and $\triangle NDL$ are similar and we have $ND:AB=ND:CD=3:1$, so $NC:CD=\color{blue}{NC:AB=2:1}$.